# Dynamically add Multiple ComboBoxes in form and read the input of added ComboBoxes?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, controls

I need to add variable numbers of ComboBoxes in my form and later I need to read the inputs from the ComboBoxes.

I  have this code-

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim n As Integer = Int(QsnNo.Text)
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While i <= n
            ComboGen(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End Sub

    Public Function ComboGen(ByVal n As Integer)
        Dim newCombo As New ComboBox
        With newCombo
            .Name = "MyComboBox" & n.ToString
            .Left = 10
            .Top = 10 + (20 * n) + 20
            .Width = 70
            .Height = 20
            .Items.Add("A")
            .Items.Add("B")
            .Visible = True
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(newCombo)
        Return 0
    End Function
```

And I can add ComboBoxes. But I want to read the inputs from the ComboBoxes later when I Click on Button2. That I can't. How can I do that?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 

    Button2.Click
            TextBox1.Text = MyComboBox1.selectedItem
        End Sub
```

I need output like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event handler to each combobox you create. This way you can easily use all comboboxes properties at runtime.

Full example:

```
    Public Class Form1
    Dim intTop As Integer = 1
    Dim strText As String
    Dim cmb As ComboBox

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        AddNewTextBox()
        AddHandler cmb.GotFocus, AddressOf cmb_Click
    End Sub

    Public Function AddNewTextBox() As ComboBox
        cmb = New ComboBox
        Me.Controls.Add(cmb)
        cmb.Top = intTop * 25
        cmb.Left = 10
        cmb.Text = "ComboBox " & Me.intTop.ToString
        intTop = intTop + 1
        Return cmb
    End Function

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox1.Text = strText
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        strText = sender.Text
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access controls by its name:

```
MsgBox(Me.Controls("MyComboBox" & intYourComboBoxNumber).SelectedItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is declare a `List(Of ComboBox)` in your form's class;

```
Private ComboBoxes As New List(Of ComboBox)
```

What you then can do is add your dynamically-created ComboBox to that list when it's created;

```
ComboBoxes.Add(newCombo)
```

To call upon this later, as long as it's not disposed, you can do, for example:

```
TextBox1.Text = ComboBoxes(0).SelectedItem ' Rather than 1, do 0 - zero-based index.
```

Also; note that `ComboGen` should be a `Sub` - not a `Function` as you're always returning `0` and never getting a "proper" result - however, you could encapsulate your code in a `Try/Catch` to return a Boolean, `True` if succeeded, `False` if not.

```
Public Function ComboGen(ByVal n As Integer) As Boolean
    Try ' Start of your Try/Catch block.
        Dim newCombo As New ComboBox
        With newCombo
            .Name = "MyComboBox" & n.ToString
            .Left = 10
            .Top = 10 + (20 * n) + 20
            .Width = 70
            .Height = 20
            .Items.Add("A")
            .Items.Add("B")
            .Visible = True
        End With
        ComboBoxes.Add(newCombo) ' Add your ComboBox to the list.
        Me.Controls.Add(newCombo)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception ' Catch your exception.
        Return False
    End Try ' End the Try/Catch block.
End Function
```